# Should I not expose the abi of the smart contract?

Tags: solidity, security, smart-contract-wallets, abi

Can anyone execute a smart contract if they get a abi?
I don't think this is good for security.
How do I ensure that only authorized people run smart contracts?

Comment: We are using a smart contract for shared distributed applications that move trust between parties to code. If your use case is different, use a different solution.

Comment: EVM smart contracts can be decompiled. Guess the ABI from binary code is not perfect, but it works. The binary code cannot be hidden because it's published on the blockchain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Security should not depend on the confidentiality of the abi.
Not disclosing the abi can increase the difficulty of carrying out the attack, but it cannot prevent the attack.
The data on the chain is public, and attackers can imitate existing transactions.
The permission check should be added to the contract code, you can refer to here
https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/access#Ownable.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, You not public abi but when you deployed smart contract to blockchain, the execute code is public with anyone so other people can decode it and know your the abi, maybe. If you want to protect you application, please choose other solution